# How to make sure current Fragment is visible in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 3 `Fragments` inside a `ViewPager`. I want to execute network calls only when the `Fragment` is **visible** to the user. Currently I am using the following method:

```
@Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
        if (menuVisible) {
            isVisible = true;

        } else {
            isVisible = false;

        }

    }
```

But the problem with the above method is giving me `getActivity()` **null** in the 1st `Fragment`. This method works fine in 2nd and 3rd `Fragment`.
I tried using `setUserVisibleHint()` but that is returning true every time.
What can be the bullet-proof solution for the above problem? I want a method that can tell me if the `Fragment` is **visible or not** to the user along with `getActivity()!=null`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying `setUserVisibleHint()`, When you are using the same Class for all 3 Fragment, You will get called 3 times or 2 times based on the position it will get call `setUserVisibleHint()`, but in that one time it will be true and remaining times will be false, because currently, one Fragment will be visible.

In that case Instead of checking only true or false, just check with true with some Id(make sure its null-pointer check, Example if you moving from 2nd position to 3rd, then 1st position arguments which we send through `setArguments` will be null).

Example:
I have one Fragment class using for 3 Fragment in my `ViewPager`, I want to animate some `View` when user come focus to the Fragment.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        startAnimation(); // If I comment this line my View will be hidden always because I am hiding the View when it's not focused on the user
    } else {
        checkAndHide();
    }
}

public void startAnimation() {
    // View might not created, when calling this, because setUserVisibleHint get call before onCreateView()
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mView != null) {

            }
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: @Hiren Added Example in my answer have a look.

Comment: I have tried the above method. But sometime I get `getActivity()` as null because its getting called before `onCreateView()` . So this answer is not helpful.

Comment: Yes, I Agree, For that, I Added a delay of 500ms using Handler, I am not saying this is the correct answer, but you can try it once.In my **startAnimation();** i have that delay.

Comment: But that will lag while swiping from one Fragment to another.

Comment: I think No, It will not, I never faced any situation like that because we are not holding UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I have face same situation finally i used this method...

This is my ViewPagerAdapter Class

```
public class MenuViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    private ArrayList<CategoryObject> arrayCategory;
    private SparseArray<Fragment> mPageReferenceMap = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
    private Context context;


    public MenuViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, RealmList<CategoryObject> arrayCategory,Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.arrayCategory = arrayCategory;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        fragment = FragmentMenuList.newInstance();
        mPageReferenceMap.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayCategory.size();
    }


    public Fragment getCurrentItem(int position) {
        return mPageReferenceMap.get(position);
    }
}
```

Below method will return current active fragment from SparseArray

```
public Fragment getCurrentItem(int position) {
            return mPageReferenceMap.get(position);
        }
```

To call that method you can use below way...

MainActivity.Java class

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
  private ViewPager viewPager;
  private ImageView imageNextCategory;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MenuViewPagerAdapter menuViewPagerAdapter = new MenuViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), arrayCategory getActivity());
   viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
   imageNextCategory=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageNextCategory);
   viewPager.setAdapter(menuViewPagerAdapter);
imageNextCategory.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
          case R.id.imageNextCategory:
Fragment fragment=menuViewPagerAdapter.getCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
if(fragment!=null){

  //isVisible() used to check if fragment is visible now
  if((YourFragment)fragment).isVisible()){
  //Here you can access any public method of your fragment
  ((YourFragment)fragment).accessMethod();
 }
}
break;
    }
  }

}
```

Hope this will help you..if any queries please tell me...this method is tested by my self. it is working perfectly..there will be any other solution but this works for me...you can clear that SparseArray once your task done with fragments.

Comment: inside `Fragment` of ViewPager what should I call ? I am clear with your `ViewPager` code but I am not sure which method to use in `Fragment`

Comment: check edited code...you have to code everything in your mainactivity from where you initialising ViewPager. In your case you can use viewPager.addOnPageChangeLister().  OnPageChageLister check that ur fragment is visible or not . if visible than make ur we service call

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: I got it solved using other method. But glad that you helped. will do implement your answer as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this **perfect** way :-

**(1)**  Add below method in **MainActivity (Activity)** class:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            int tabPos = MainActivity.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
            if(tabPos == 1) {
                FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager,1);
                firstFragment.refreshOnTabChanged();
            }
            else if(tabPos == 2) {
                SecondFragment secondFragment = (SecondFragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager,2);
                secondFragment.refreshOnTabChanged();
            }
//              Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(MainActivity.mViewPager.getCurrentItem()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });
```

**And** add below method in fragment(s):-

```
public void refreshOnTabChanged() {
// Write code for network call
    mTypeVolleyService();
}
```

---

**OR**

Try below solution if you have `tabLayout.

In **MainActivity (Activity)** class add below method inside `onCreate()` method:-

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int tabPos = tab.getPosition();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tabPos);

            if(tabPos == 1) {
                FirstFragment firstFragment = (FirstFragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager,1);
                firstFragment.refreshOnTabChanged();
            }
            else if(tabPos == 2) {
                SecondFragment secondFragment = (SecondFragment) mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager,2);
                secondFragment.refreshOnTabChanged();
            }
//              Toast.makeText(context, ""+tabPos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        });
```

And add below method in fragment(s):-

```
public void refreshOnTabChanged() {
// Write code for network call
    mTypeVolleyService();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am not using tab. I am just changing the fragments by sliding.

Comment: OK then let me check if I can provide solution.

Comment: Yeah please. will be of great help.